# How to give a error message when one or more fields are not given a value in ASP.Net 6.0 Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

The user is able to post an outfit (a image/picture) to the website.
If the user wants to post an outfit, he needs to give the outfit some values. The outfit needs to have a : **Price**, **title**, **path** (from file explorer) and a **category** (which is an enum).

The category can be chosen via a drop down menu, the title and price are given a value via a textbox.

So the conclusion is, to be able to post an outfit, you need to upload an image and give that image some values all in the same view. If one of the attributes isn't given a value (so for example no image is chosen, or the price is  not given a value) there should be an error :
one of the fields is missing.

When all attributes are given a value, the outfit with the given values goes to the database.

this is my outfit  model:

```
public class OutfitVM
{
    public enum OutfitCategory
    {
        Trendy,
        Chic,
        Oldschool,
        Casual
    }

        [Required]
        public int? Prijs { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? Titel { get; set; }
        public string? FileAdress { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public OutfitCategory? DeCategory { get; }
        public bool Retry { get; set; }

        //public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; } = new List<Review>();

        public OutfitVM(string titel, int prijs, string fileadress, OutfitCategory 
        category)
    {
        this.Titel = titel;
        this.Prijs = prijs;
        this.FileAdress = fileadress;
        DeCategory = category;
    }
    
    public OutfitVM()
    {

    }
}
```

This is the controller so far:

```
  public class ToevoegController : Controller
        {
                private readonly ILogger<ToevoegController> _logger;
    
            public ToevoegController(ILogger<ToevoegController> logger)
            {
                _logger = logger;
            }
    
            public ActionResult OutfitToevoegen()  //IActionresult is een interface en 
                actionresult is een implimentatie daarvan
            {
                OutfitVM outfitVM = new OutfitVM();
                outfitVM.Retry = false;
                return View(outfitVM);
                //dit uitleg? wrm maak je nieuwe vm aan en wrm geef je die mee aan view
            }
    
            [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult OutfitToevoegen(OutfitVM outfit)
            {
                   
      
            }
        }
```

So inside the HttpPost method there should be some code which tells the program to give an error if one or more of the attributes I mentioned earlier is not given a value.

```
OutfitCategory = category (which is chosen via a drop down menu)
Prijs = price (which is given a value via a textbox)
Title = title (which is given a value via a textbox)
FileAdress = path (which is automatically given a value when the user chooses a picture from file explorer)
```

Once every attribute of the outfit is given a value, then the outfit (image) and the values associated with it go to the database.

Thanks!

Comment: There are lot of way to do that. One is [`model validation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#model-state) or  [`model bindings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#model-state). You can use `[Required]` as of your controller like `public IActionResult OutfitToevoegen([Required] OutfitVM outfit)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So inside the HttpPost method there should be some code wich tells the program to give an error if one or more of the attributes i mentioned earlier is not given a value?

There are lot of way to achieve that. One is [`model validation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#model-state) or  [`model bindings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#model-state).
You can use `[Required]` as of your controller like `public IActionResult OutfitToevoegen([Required] OutfitVM outfit)`

**Controller:**

Model bindings using [`Required`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#non-nullable-properties-on-generic-types-and-required-attribute) annotations can do the [`Model bindings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#non-nullable-properties-on-generic-types-and-required-attribute) on controller level

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult OutfitToevoegen([Required] OutfitVM outfit)
    {

        return Ok(outfit);
    }
```

**Sample Model:**

```
public class OutfitVM
    {
        public string Prijs { get; set; }
        public string Titel { get; set; }
        public string FileAdress { get; set; }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:**

If you check the captured screenshot, you would seen when I have sent empty request it responded with the `400` saying validation got failed as below:

[image]

So using `[Required]` annotation you can handle this without writing
any extra validation code for that. `[Required]` as your `controller action` argument will do that.